# Xamarin forms vs Flutter vs Cordova (Can we call the application developed in Flutter as a Native app ?)

Tags: react-native, flutter, cordova, xamarin.forms, hybrid-mobile-app

One question is lingering in my mind since long time ..

I don't have much experience in mobile app development, but I did develop couple of applications in Cordova and Unity3d.

I know that when we develop app in Cordova using Angular, it's rendering its UI using Web view of respective devices. More like a web application running inside a native app shell.

How about Xamarin and Flutter, Xamarin always use the buzz word "native" is Xamarin really builds completely native app? not using the web view ?, if thats the case how about Flutter? is flutter still doing what Cordova doing or is it building completely native app ??

Let me put it in a different way
Can we call the application developed in Flutter as a Native app ?

Comment: Yes, Xamarin uses native controls and not a webview. Flutter uses neither, it [draws controls itself](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#does-flutter-use-my-operating-systems-built-in-platform-widgets).

Comment: Native controls are good but sometimes you need to make use of other well-developed libraries, for example MathJax (LaTeX renderer in JavaScript) to render mathematics expressions,  in your projects so the webview is still a hero!

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, but actually no. Apps on Flutter look like native as it draws the interface for each platform, yet the code base stays the same for Android and iOS. So it's kinda native and not at the same time. If you are interested in Cordova vs Flutter, you can read [this comparison](https://surf.dev/flutter-vs-apache-cordova/), it gives a nice and clear understanding of what their pros and cons, might be useful for your project